# How to make a <select> with options that enable/disable a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, select, onchange

How to make a multiple choice question that enables a button when the right answer is selected? Here is what I tried:

```js
function enAble() {
  let possibleAns = document.getElementById('question').value;

  if (possibleAns != 1) {
    document.getElementById("btton").disabled = true;
  } else if (possibleAns = 1) {
    document.getElementById("btton").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="question" onchange="enAble()">
  <option>wrong answer</option>
  <option value="1">right answer</option>
  <option>wrong answer</option>
</select>

<button id="btton" type="button" disabled>button</button>
```

Comment: What's your specific question? Does your code give a different result than expected? How is it different? This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `else if (possibleAns = 1) {`, `(possibleAns = 1)` is an assignment statement. Use `else if (possibleAns == 1) {` to check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Change possibleAns !=1
to possibleAns !==1

Also use possibleAns ===1 in else statement

Comment: In your else statement, you are using single = instead of ==. 
Also you can use parseInt(possibleAns) === 1) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A cleanest way to code that (Imho).

```js
const 
  select_element = document.getElementById('question')
, button_element = document.getElementById("btton")
  ;
select_element.onchange = () =>
  {
  button_element.disabled = (select_element.value != '1')
  }
```

```html
<select id="question">
  <option value="0">wrong answer</option>
  <option value="1">right answer</option>
  <option value="2">wrong answer</option>
</select>

<button id="btton" type="button" disabled>
  button
</button>
```